# Securing a "Google Sheet Web App" API with a KEY / Password / Secret word

Tags: google-apps-script

I watched the following video on YouTube >> [Apps Script: JSON Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQzPIVJf6-w&t=290s)
 where the "instructor" teaches how to convert a Google Sheet into a simple API which returns some data into a JSON format.

At minute: 04:50 he mentions that once the web app has been published, the data becomes available and is not secured in any way. In case we`d like to secure it, we`d have to do this by using a "KEY" which we can extract from the parameter of the "function doGet(event){}" function.

My questions are:

As a developer of the Google Apps Script:

- How exactly do we set this key in our Google Apps Script?
- How do we verify that the external web application which is making a GET request to our API is providing this special KEY? I suppose we`d have to use some kind of: "event.SOMETHING"?

As a developer of the web application which is going to be making the GET requests to the "API:

- what the code should look like from the side of the web application making the GET request?

Please, forgive me in case my questions are dumb or unclear. As a person who`s currently trying to learn Google Apps Script, I realize I might not be explaining the best possible way the things I cannot understand / I do not know.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the author of that video was suggesting that you pass it as a parameter in a query string.  The author didn't actually provide much detail but I think he was suggesting a key like an API key or even username and password.  In either case that would require you to have extra code to authenticate each operation.

Comment: I think you are right. I thought it was much more complicated / there was a different way of authentication when it comes to the "event" in doGet(event).

Thanks a lot for your time and help Cooper.